# Not able to use System namespace in Visual C++ ATL project

Tags: c++, namespaces, atl

I am having a ATL project where in I have to use System namespace to set environment variables. I tried:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
```

in my dllmain.cpp file.

While building, I got:

> fatal error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option  even after adding /clr option project->properties->common language runtime support.

If I remove #using mscorlib.dll, I am getting:

> error C2871: 'System' : a namespace with this name does not exist

How can I use this namespace in my ATL project?

Comment: "i have to use System namespace to set environment variables" what environment variables are you talking about? (e.g.)

Comment: they are custom environment whereas the target is Machine. So i am using System::Environment and System::EnvironmentVariableTarget using the following
**Environment::SetEnvironmentVariable("variablename", "variablevalue",EnvironmentVariableTarget::Machine);**

Comment: sounds as if your app is not .net but you are trying to call a .net library. you could use the normal winapi instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. but i want to set the variable in machine level with minimum code and is there any way to use the above library in atl project?

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f1edaf4-2ea5-42e6-a4c7-0cc0a98ad62b/managed-targeted-code-requires-a-clr-option?forum=vcgeneral) from MSDN.

I quote the answer here:

> As you are including a reference to mscorlib.dll you need to let the
> compiler know that you are targetting the .NET Runtime. The compiler
> switch that controls this is /clr - hence the error message you are
> seeing. To enable this option from the project system in the Solution
> Explorer pane right-click on your project, select Configuration
> Properties.General and then select "Common Language Runtime support"
> and from the drop-down list select "Common Language Runtime Support
> (/clr)".
>
> In C++ identifiers are case-sensitive: I suspect that the name should
> be System::Console.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But as i mentioned in the question, the /clr is already set in the Configuration properties-> General. I am using System::Environment and System::EnvironmentVariableTarget. I tried using the namespace as you mentioned, but it dint help.

Comment: #using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Console;   try this

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the question. It is actually #using <mscorlib.dll> in my code

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please accept the answer by click on the check, thank you :)